# Como agregar una key a un objeto dentro de un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con react y tengo un useState "posts" que es un array con esta estructura:

```
[{objectID:"123", nombre:"jhon",age:"21"},{objectID:"123", nombre:"jhoni",age:"21"},.....]
```

Y otro array con la misma estructura llamado myFav al cual se le agregan o quitan objetos apretando un boton

quiero comparar estos dos arrays y agregarle una key llamada "like" al estado "posts" de esta forma si un objectID de myFav aparese en el estado "posts" quiero agregale a ese objeto dentro de post que tiene ese objectID  la key like: true

de forma que

```
 // nota que esto es un state creado asi const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
          posts = [{objectID:"123", nombre:"jhon",age:"21"},{objectID:"123", nombre:"jhoni",age:"21"},.....]
 

myFave =[{objectID:"123", nombre:"jhon",age:"21"},{objectID:"1212", nombre:"jhoni",age:"21"},.....]
```

resulta en el estado post:

```
 post =[{objectID:"123", nombre:"jhon",age:"21",like:true},{objectID:"123", nombre:"jhoni",age:"21"},.....]
```

hay alguna forma de hacer esto e estado investigando enverdad no se como hacer esto

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se trata de comparar variables (tipos primitivos) no tenemos mayor problema

```
let a = "manzana"
let b = "manzana"
console.log(a === b); //resultado true
```

o tambien

```
let a = 1
let b = 1
console.log(a === b); //resultado true
```

pero cuando se trata de comparar objetos o arrays la cosa cambia:

```
let a = {nombre: "julio", edad: 20}
let b = {nombre: "julio", edad: 20}
console.log(a === b) //resultado false
```

o tambien

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
let b = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(a === b) //resultado false
```

va a resultar falso por la forma en la que js maneja la memoria, al comparar arrays, objetos o funciones estamos comparando referencias a esos objetos (direcciones de memoria)

La forma sencilla de comparar objetos es convirtiendolos a una cadena, de esta forma si podremos obtener igualdad:

```
let a = JSON.stringify({nombre: "julio", edad: 20})
let b = JSON.stringify({nombre: "julio", edad: 20})
console.log(a === b) //resultado true
```

Lo malo aqui es que si el orden de las propiedades no es el mismo la comparacion sera false.

Por lo tanto si post y myFave van a tener la misma estructura y cantidad de objetos este metodo te servira:

```
if(JSON.stringify(posts[0]) === JSON.stringify(myFave[0])){
myFave[0] = {...myFave[0], like: true} //con el spread operator le agrego la propiedad
console.log(myFave);
}
```

Sino ya tendras que usar bucles forin para comparar claves/valor